# Two MYSQL Table compare number of unique rows

Tags: php, mysql

```
    Table 1
    ID Customer Tracking
    --------------------
    1  Nick       434
    2  Jhon       437
    3  Nick       456
    4  Mike       544

Table 2
B_ID Customer Process
----------------------
1   Nick      Payment
2   Tom       Payment
3   Nick      Payment
4   Mike      Payment
5   Nick      Payment

    Echo
    Table 1  Table 2
    ------------------
    Nick 2   Nick 3
    Mike 1   Mike 1
```

How to select only simillar values from two different table and count rows.
As you see we have 2 Nick in the Table 1 and 3 Nick in the table 2.

So I want show only similar customers from both table.

Comment: Between the two tables you can join on the matching values to get the list of matching data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter duplicates in SQL join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029787/filter-duplicates-in-sql-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `count` each table (grouped by the name) and join the results:

```
SELECT customer1, cnt1, customer2, cnt2
FROM   (SELECT   customer AS customer1, COUNT(*) AS cnt1
        FROM     table1
        GROUP BY customer) t1
JOIN   (SELECT   customer AS customer2, COUNT(*) AS cnt2
        FROM     table2
        GROUP BY customer) t2 ON customer1 = customer2
```

Comment: what is customer 1 and customer2?

Comment: The customers from table1 and table2 respectively. They are aliases defined by the `AS` clause in each subquery.

Comment: Result: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @user3391807 yeah, forgot the table aliases. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Write subqueries that get the customer counts from each table, then join them.

```
SELECT t1.customer, t1.count AS Table1, t2.count AS Table2
FROM (SELECT customer, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY customer) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT customer, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM Table2
      GROUP BY customer) AS t2
ON t1.customer = t2.customer
```